# Searching more than 1 column

Tags: php, mysql

I have set up a a search function for my database to look for names of siblings. I have run into a problem in that the siblings are listed in more than one column. I was wondering if you can use the WHERE with OR to look into 3 or more columns in a data base.

This is what i have now

```
SELECT * FROM movie WHERE $dropdown_1 LIKE '%$search%'"
```

The `dropdown_1` can be several different things including siblings but I would like when siblings is selected in `dropdown_1` it will look at `siblings_1`, `siblings_2`, `siblings_3` and `siblings_4` to see if a name matches.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably time to consider [Normalizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your database.

To directly answer your question, you can use `OR` for multiple matches

```
`siblings_1` LIKE '%search%' OR `siblings_2` LIKE '%search%' # etc...
```

Alternatively, as OMGPonnies pointed out in the comment below, using `UNION` is faster:

```
WHERE siblings_1 LIKE '%search%' UNION SELECT ... WHERE siblings_2 LIKE '%search%' # etc ...
```

But I insist, if you can still help it, to redesign your database :).

Comment: @OMGPonies Thanks for that, I'm curious though, how would you rewrite that using a `UNION`? :)

Comment: `WHERE siblings_1 LIKE '%search%' UNION SELECT ... WHERE siblings_2 LIKE '%search%'...`

Comment: @OMGPonies: I curious about why the use of UNION instead of OR. Is it something to do with the way MySQL optimizes the queries?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes - `OR` is a notoriously performer, on pretty much any database I've used.  `IN` would be an option, if it weren't for the `LIKE` comparison.

Comment: @OMGPonies: It's sad when a UNION with its resultant 'duplicate elimination' phase is still faster than an OR'd query.  Of course, you need enough parentheses in the right places to make the OR'd query work correctly, and you might get better performance if there are other filter conditions than just the OR'd one.  I've seen that problem before; some DBMS have largely conquered it, I believe, but probably not all.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I don't see what's "sad" about getting the best performance possible.  Every language has it's quirks - test & consult the explain/query plan to see what works best.

Comment: @OMGPonies I'll edit my answer with `UNION`, that ok with you?

Comment: @OMGPonies: it means the optimizer is...sadly lacking?...when it can't out-optimize you on something as straight-forward as an N-way OR condition on a single column.  It means you have to put in effort working around its deficiency, effort that shouldn't be necessary.  If the 'sort unique' plus processing N-times as many queries outperforms the OR'd query, then the optimizer is not in a happy state. Maybe it should internally treat the OR as a UNION style operation. There's nothing wrong with wringing the utmost out of the system; you just shouldn't have to do that much work to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Putting column names in user-defined variables is a bad idea, as then they are able to search anywhere in your table.

What you probably need is more like

```
SELECT * FROM movie WHERE `dropdown_column` LIKE '%$search%'" OR `sibling_column` LIKE '%$search%'" etc..
```