# Search a string in multiple fields of a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table **User** which has the fields **(id, first_name, middle_name, last_name).**

I want to write a query to find a user by his name. The name may be first name, middle name or last name.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user 
        WHERE first_name like '%$name%' OR  
              middle_name like '%$name%' OR
              last_name like '%$name%'";
```

Is it efficient query?
(Leave the security issue for the time being.)

Comment: Is it efficient when compared to what?

Comment: According to this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986678/searching-more-than-1-column/9986696#comment12762483_9986696 UNION is faster

Comment: @Jon I want to get a better query to do that task. I am not comparing with anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alter table and add composite Fulltext index on `First_name,second_name,last_name` then use this query

```
select * 
from table_name 
where match (`First_name`,`second_name`,`last_name`) against('name')
```

It's pretty much faster then your query.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you have a `LIKE '%something%'` in your WHERE clause, you force a table scan.  So yes, it is inefficient, but one or three `LIKE` statements will make little difference.

The table scan is the big performance hit.

Consider looking at MySQL's [Full Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html) capability.  It is designed to answer this type of query much more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to search for a pattern in more than one fields, and **if you have the permission to change table schema**, i would suggest implementing [FULL-TEXT SEARCH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

Hope it helps :)